# How can I animate the text color of a TextView when using shared elements transitions?

Tags: android, animation, textview, shared-element-transition

I have shared elements transition animations working but the TextView that is animated has a different color in the second activity. 
What happens is that at the start of the animation the color changes abruptly to the end color instead of changing gradually.

Anyone knows how I can achieve this effect?